# Linux recursive removal is not working

Tags: linux, command-line

I am trying to delete a *massive* directory and cannot get the `rm` command to work.

I want to delete the `widget` directory which contains thousands of files and folders. Obviously I do not want to descend into each subdirectory and have to confirm the deletion for all 5,000 files/folders.

So I type:

```
rm -r widget
```

The prompt asks me:

```
rm: descend into directory 'widget'?
```

I type `no` and then re-run an `ls`. **The folder is still there.**  If I rerun the `rm -r widget` command, but instead this time type `yes`, it will descend into the massive subdirectory structure as predicted.

What is going on here?

Comment: Type `alias` in the shell. Is there one for `rm` that looks like `alias rm='rm -i'`?

Comment: `rm -r widget` should normally ask if -f isn't given, shouldn't it? Or did I add that alias and completely forget about it?

Comment: @Rob it must be that the -i is set. `rm -r`deletes recursive and asks for readonly files, `rm -ri` shows the above behaviour and `rm -rf` just removes.

Comment: I set it up so long ago I didn't even remember, that'll save me one day, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are typing no you are telling it not to recurse down into the widgets directory.

This is why when you typed in yes later on that it did go and delete them.

If you use `rm -rf Widgets` it will not prompt you for confirmation, but you don't get a second chance if you typo